# Grey items in the blender file and orphan data which can't be purged and find in view layer

Tags: blend-files

My project file has become bigger and bigger and I find a lot of stuff I can't purge and even can't find in the view layer tab, but they exist in the orphan data and blender file tab, what are they and how can I purge them permanently?

[image]